# Gradle generated LibGDX project does not work in NetBeans

Tags: java, libgdx

I have to do rework of Worms (game) and I've chosen LibGDX. So, I've installed Gradle and generated a new project in LibGDX app - as they have in the documentation. But when I'm trying to load it as a project in NetBeans, it does not work. NetBeans sees it as a pure folder, not a project folder. I've also tried to manually create a project and paste there just the `main` that was generated and as expected, I've got errors with the imports (it does not know those imports).

What do I have to do? Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install a [gradle plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support) for NetBeans and then reimport the project again by using the plugin.

> A community-contributed plugin is available for Gradle, the Groovy-based build system. The plugin lets you open Gradle projects into the IDE, create new Gradle projects, and invoke Gradle commands in the IDE.

Also, [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans) official Libgdx wiki for NetBeans may be helpful.